# Adding multiple for each in the call back function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to the `react redux.` Here what I am trying to do is that,

I have a function which gets called on the click of a checkbox.

```
handleCheckBox = () => {
    this.setState({
      isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd,
      isEnable: !this.state.isCheckd ? true : false
    }, () => {
      this.props.untracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd }))
    });
  }
```

Now in this function , I have a callback in which I am using a foreach loop on one array which has multiple objects.

Now, I want to call another callback function in the same the way after likem

```
 handleCheckBox = () => {
    this.setState({
      isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd,
      isEnable: !this.state.isCheckd ? true : false
    }, () => {
      this.props.untracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd })),
this.props.tracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd }))
    });
  }
```

like this.

```
  handleTableCheckboxChange = (e, type) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
    }, () => {
      const checkedItems = this.props[type].filter((item) => this.state[item.resumeId])
      this.setState({
        isCheckd: checkedItems.length === this.props[type].length ? true : false,
        isEnable: checkedItems.length > 1 ? true : false
      });
    });
  }
```

So, Is there any way to do this ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can do it in the same way what your code snippets you showed...

Comment: Side note: You're breaking one of the [fundamental rules of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous): When you're setting state based on existing state, you can't use the version of `setState` that accepts an object, you **must** use the callback version. So in `handleCheckBox`: `this.setState(({isCheckd}) => ({isCheckd: !isCheckd, isEnable: !isCheckd}), () => /* ... */);` Also note that `!flag ? true : false` is pointless, `!flag` is exactly the same thing.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you just add that as an answer.

Comment: So, it will be like   handleCheckBox = () => {
    this.setState(({ isCheckd }) => ({ isCheckd: !isCheckd, isEnable: !isCheckd }), () =>
      this.props.untracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd }))
    );
  }

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added one more function in which also I am updating the statae. So, is this the right way ?

Comment: @sathishkumar it is giving  me error

Comment: @ganesh - No, because again, you're using state (`this.state.isCheckd`) when setting state, but not using the callback version of `setState`.

Comment: Actually really I am kind of getting confused.It would be really helpful if you add that as an answer.

Comment: @ganesh what error did you get?

Comment: No , it was just a typo sorry for that

Comment: @ganesh - I don't think it's an answer to your question. (I can't really figure out what your question is.) It's *related* to your question, but I don't think it *answers* it. I suggest reading the [page I linked](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) thoroughly (really, all of the pages in that tutorial).

Comment: No it is not an answer to my question. Actually, what I was asking is I have to call another foreach  just after the previous foreach.

Comment: So, one thing is that I have added some code in the comment just after your comment so, is this the way you were suggesting to update the state ?

Comment: @sathishkumar  Line 66:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions  this is the error that i am getting

Comment: another problem that I am getting is that whichever foreach I write that only get update to the state, other does not get change. It is just diff array of obj but the state is the same. So, why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma(,) at end of the forEach and put ;

```
handleCheckBox = () => {
    this.setState({
      isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd,
      isEnable: !this.state.isCheckd ? true : false
    }, () => {
      //remove the comma at end of the forEach and put ;
      this.props.untracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd }));
this.props.tracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd }));
    });
  }
```